# How to set ticks in Seaborn FacetGrid?

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, xticks

I have a code like this, and I want to add ticks on the X-axis  so I could see better what the value over 150 corresponds to, for example.  the range for my X-values is from 178 to 17639.

```
bins = np.linspace(df.days_with_cr_line.min(), df.days_with_cr_line.max(), 32)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="loan_status", hue="loan_status", palette=['#8856a7', '#f03b20'], col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.hist, 'days_with_cr_line', bins=bins, ec="k")
```

[image]

I have tried

```
g.set_xticks(np.arange(0,18000,500), minor=True)
AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_xticks'
```

and

```
for axes in g.axes.flat:
    _ = axes.set_xticks(axes.get_xticks(range(0,18000)))
```

this removes the tick labels without adding any ticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use set to set the number of ticks on the x-axis, and then set the tick labels for them, you will get the intended result. The data is created appropriately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(20210831)
df = pd.DataFrame({'days_with_cr_line':np.random.randint(10,1000,size=1000),
                  'loan_status':np.random.choice(['Fully paid','Not fully paid'], size=1000)})
bins = np.linspace(df.days_with_cr_line.min(), df.days_with_cr_line.max(), 32)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="loan_status", hue="loan_status", palette=['#8856a7', '#f03b20'], col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.hist, 'days_with_cr_line', bins=bins, ec="k")
g.set(xticks=np.arange(0,1050,50))
g.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0,1050,50), rotation=90)
```

[image]